# getting error in calling column in dataframe

Tags: pandas, sklearn-pandas

I import a excel file and and when I call any column by its name then it gives me error.and after performing some calculation when I try to export into csv file then I find every (A-cap) with every column name.

I have following dataframe.

```
Date            AGTL      ATLH      GHNI
2010-01-05  0.008738  0.009699  0.000000
2010-01-06 -0.003659 -0.000070  0.018519
2010-01-07  0.016423  0.020710  0.006532
2010-01-08 -0.007279 -0.000069  0.002601
2010-01-11  0.000898 -0.007830 -0.026317
2010-01-12 -0.000775 -0.017472  0.023717
2010-01-13  0.005616  0.036284 -0.005222
2010-01-14 -0.005616  0.003747 -0.042787
```

I get the following Error when I try to call a column by its index name

```
df['AGTL']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-20-fadf2850086a>", line 1, in <module>
    df['AGTL']

  File "E:\Users\Hussnain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "E:\Users\Hussnain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'AGTL'
```

Comment: There might be whitespaces in your column name. Try `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` Then call the column again: `df['AGTL']`

Answer (score 0):

If AGTL is index column then first do

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

There are chances column name contains trailing spaces

```
 df.columns = map(str.strip, list(df.columns))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try list your columns with list(df) and then iterating through them to ensure that the column you're looking for exists.

```
for col in list(df):
    df[col]
```

The column may also contain trailing whitespace, you try using str.strip()

Answer (score 0):

Check first the name of your columns: `df.columns`

This will give you the right name and you will see if you have additional whitespaces in them.

If you find additional whitespaces and you want to remove them then use this:

```
df.columns = [col.strip(' ') for col in df.columns]
```

The above line should solve the problem regardless if the number of extra whitespace in each column is the same or not.

after that, you escape having that error.

Hope this helps